Ejecutar archivo al ejecutar npm run dev
estoy haciendo un proyecto en el cual aplique webscraping, pero no se ejecuta automaticamente cuando hago npm run dev en local o por ejemplo. Entonces si lo pongo en produccion se quedará con un precio y necesito que se actualize cada hora. Ayuda, gracias!
import { chromium } from "playwright";
import fs from "fs";

async function getDollarPrice(params) {
    const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: true });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://www.bcv.org.ve/");

    const priceDollar = await page.$$eval(
        "#dolar * strong",
        (elements) =>
            elements.map(
            (el) =>
                +parseFloat(
                    el.innerText.replace(",", ".")
                ).toFixed(2)
            )[0]
     );

     await browser.close();
     const dataString = JSON.stringify({
         price: priceDollar,
     });
     const folder = "./public";

     fs.writeFileSync(
        `${folder}/priceDollar.json`,
         dataString,
         (err) => {
              if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
              } else {
                  console.log("Data saved");
              }
     }
 );
   console.log(priceDollar);
}
setInterval(() => {
    getDollarPrice();
}, 3600000);

Este es el codigo de mi script para hacer el webscraping y obtener el precio del dolar en bolivares, de verdad agradeceria mucho si me puede ayudar
{
    "name": "selfiestore",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
     "dev": "vite",
     "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
     "lint": "eslint .",
     "preview": "vite preview"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "express": "^4.21.0",
      "playwright": "^1.47.2",
      "puppeteer": "^23.5.0",
      "react": "^18.3.1",
      "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
      "react-router-dom": "^6.26.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@eslint/js": "^9.9.0",
      "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
      "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
      "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
      "eslint": "^9.9.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.9",
      "globals": "^15.9.0",
      "typescript": "^5.5.3",
      "typescript-eslint": "^8.0.1",
      "vite": "^5.4.1"
    }
   }

Ese es el package.json, desconozco si debo agregar algun comando, cualquier ayuda mil gracias!

Sin código no te podemos ayudar.

Cómo es el archivo package.json?

Listo, package.json agregado
